# How Might We Hide the Workbox From Certain Users?

Tags: workbox

We have a role for content contributors who aren't allowed to perform any of the actions in the Workbox (Sitecore 9.2).  To avoid confusion and mischief, we'd like to hide the Workbox from these users altogether:  i.e., hide the Workbox button on the Launchpad and the links on the Content Editor and the Desktop "All Applications" menu.  There's lots of information around about how to show, hide, enable and disable *Workflow* states, but not much about how to manipulate the *Workbox*, so I'm not real clear how to go about this.

Comment: Did you try disabling read access to these items for your custom role? /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing/Workbox, 
/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Programs/Workbox, 
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Applications/WorkboxForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the new role has read access to everything. In Sitecore, when you assign access rights to items, they always inherit the access right that is assigned to their parent item in the content tree. However, if you need to, you can overrule the inherited rights on an item by assigning access rights specifically on the item or denying the item the right to inherit.

So I'd recommend to create a new role called `DenyWorkboxAccess` that denies read access. Apply this role only to those content contributors who aren't allowed to perform any of the actions in the Workbox.

Follow the below steps to set up new role/permission.

1. Click on `Role Manger` from Launchpad.
2. Click on the `New` button at the top left corner of the ribbon.
3. Add the role name `DenyWorkboxAccess` and click Ok.
4. Find the newly created role (you can search it now using search box). Click on the role row to select it then click on `Security Editor` from tool group on the ribbon.
5. Find these items and deny the read access by clicking the X button for each item.

   `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing/Workbox`

   `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Programs/Workbox`

   `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Applications/WorkboxForm`
6. Applied "DenyWorkboxAccess" to users.

It would look like the below screen once you deny read access.
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: A clarification for those who look at this later:  these items to be hidden are in the Core database.